# Advantages of approaching a problem by formulating a cost function that is globally optimizable

Tags: optimization, function

This is a rather general question (i.e. not necessarily specific to statistics), but I have noticed a trend in the machine learning and statistical literature where authors prefer to follow the following approach:

**Approach 1**: Obtain a solution to a practical problem by formulating a cost function for which it is possible (e.g. from a computational standpoint) to find a globally optimal solution (e.g. by formulating a convex cost function).

rather than:

**Approach 2**: Obtain a solution to the same problem by formulating a cost function for which we may not be able to obtain a globally optimal solution (e.g. we can only get a locally optimal solution for it).

Note that rigorously speaking the two problems are different; the assumption is that we can find the globally optimal solution for the first one, but not for the second one.

Other considerations aside (i.e. speed, ease of implementation, etc.), I am looking for:

1. An **explanation** of this trend (e.g. mathematical or historical arguments)
2. **Benefits** (practical and/or theoretical) for following Approach 1 instead of 2 when solving a practical problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My believe is that the goal should be to optimize the function you are interested in. If that happens to be the number of misclassifications - and not a binomial likelihood, say - then you should try minimizing the number of misclassifications. However, for the number of practical reasons mentioned (speed, implementation, instability etc), this may not be so easy and it may even be impossible. In that case, we choose to approximate the solution.

I know of basically two approximation strategies; either we come up with algorithms that attempt to directly approximate the solution of the original problem, or we reformulate the original problem as a more directly solvable problem (e.g. convex relaxations).

A **mathematical** argument for preferring one approach over the other is whether we can understand a) the properties of the solution actually computed and b) how well the solution approximates the solution of the problem we are actually interested in.

I know of many results in statistics where we can prove properties of a solution to a  optimization problem. To me it seems more difficult to analyze the solution of an
algorithm, where you don't have a mathematical formulation of what it computes (e.g. that it solves a given optimization problem). I certainly won't claim that you can't, but it seems to be a **theoretical benefit**, if you can give a clear mathematical formulation of what you compute.

It is unclear to me, if such mathematical arguments give any **practical benefits** to Approach 1 over Approach 2. There are certainly somebody out there, [who are not afraid of a non-convex loss function](http://videolectures.net/eml07_lecun_wia/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Yann LeCun's talk. I look forward to watching it.

Answer (score 1):

@NRH provided an answer to this question (over 5 years ago), so I'll just offer an Approach 3, which combines Approaches 1 and 2.

**Approach 3**:

1. Formulate and solve to global optimality a convex, or in any event, globally optimizable (not necessarily convex), problem which is "close" to the problem you really want to solve.
2. Use the globally optimal solution from step 1 as the starting (initial) solution to a non-convex optimization problem you really want to solve (or more want to solve than the problem solved in step 1). Hope that your starting solution is in the "region of attraction" to the global optimum relative to the solution method employed to solve the non-convex optimization problem you really want to solve.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: It is not exactly Mark's case, but a common approach in many computer vision problems is to use [graduated non-convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduated_optimization) to obtain a sequence of "good" local optima on related problems. A concrete example is [coarse to fine optical flow](https://www.google.com/#q=optical+flow+coarse+to+fine&start=20) where for a pair of images, a coarse-scale alignment is used to seed the search at finer scales, moving through a pair of [image pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)).

Comment: @horaceT Let's say you want to solve a nonlinear least squares problem $y$ ~ $ae^{bx}$, which is non-convex. As step 1, you could solve the linear least squares problem $y$ ~ $aa + bb x$, which is convex and can be solved to global optimality. Then in step 2 use $a = e^{aa_{optimal}}, b = bb_{optimal}$ as starting values for the nonlinear least squares. The problems are similar, but the errors are treated differently.  There are many problems in which a non-convex penalty is desired (for step 2), but could be replaced with a convex penalty for step 1. Multiple iterations are also possible.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 What you described is similar in spirit, and overlaps with what are called homotopy methods, in which a path to the solution of the problem you really want to solve is traced out by solving a series of problems in which a parameter, such as a constraint bound, is gradually changed and successive problems solved, for which the first problem is easy to solve from scratch. It could indeed be the case that the first problem is convex, or otherwise amenable to solution, but later problems might not be, even though their optimal solution might be continuous in the parameter.